# How to add a popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is me code , I need some help , That ho can i add a popup for confirmation after someone clicks on delete button.
Please help.

```
        <tbody>
            <?php  
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_query)){
                    $name = $row['name'];
            ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $name;  ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="service-delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm " data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="delete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            <?php } ?>  

        </tbody>

    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please format your code to make it readable.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a dialog box with two buttons that return only true or false, then you can use `confirm()`. Confirm returns true on clicking **OK** button and false on clicking **Cancel** button .You just said you need only confirmation. So in your script add a onclick function on delete button

```
var confirmation = Confirm ('Are you sure to delete ?');
if(confirmation){
// If yes
}else{
// If no
}
```

OR if you want a popup with some forms, then you could use a dialog box.

```
$( function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  } );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete_button" id="delete_button<?php echo $res['employeeID']; ?>" onclick="delete_row(<?php echo $res['employeeID']; ?>);"><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span></button>
```

---

```
<script>
// Single Record Delete 
function delete_row(employeeID)
{
    var id = employeeID;

    if(confirm("Are you sure want to delete?")) {
        $.ajax
        ({
            type:'post',
            url:'employeeDelete.php',
            data:{
                    delete_row:'delete_row',
                    row_id:employeeID,
                },
            success:function() {

                    $('tr#'+id+'').css('background-color', '#ccc');
                    $('tr#'+id+'').fadeOut('slow');
                    location.reload();
            }
        });
    }return false;
}
```